# How to find the users which are part of a firebase app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project in Firebase.This project has 2 apps:
1.Android
2.iOS

I want to know which users are registered from android platform & likewise from iOS.

Is there a way to know ?

Comment: may be there is no way to find android users and ios users directly, you have store a `boolean` value like **isAndroid** in user table in firebase database while registration and after login fetch the value from user table.

Comment: That can be one of the solution.Thanks !

Comment: can i put my comment suggestion as answer, will you accept it ?.

Comment: Go ahead Nirav,i accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there is no way to find android users and iOS users directly, you have to store a `boolean` value like for an example **isAndroid** in user table in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) while registration and after login fetch the value of **isAndroid** from user table and accordingly do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in API in Firebase Authentication to know what platform a user signed in from. So if you want to see that information, you will have to find it elsewhere.

As Nirav commented, one way would be to track it in an online database (e.g. the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), or [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)), and have your code set it.

If you only want to know how many users sign in from each platform, and don't care about each individual user, you can also consider using [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) to track the information.