# Create new database for development

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am about to release my first app using firebase RDB and once the app goes live I would still like to have access to a database that I can mess with for testing purposes.

Should I create a new database instance and then just modify the config object?

```
let config = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "newDatabase.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://newDatabase.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "newDatabase",
      storageBucket: "newDatabase",
      messagingSenderId: "123456789"
    }
```

Would this the right way to create a development database?

Comment: I am not sure how you will create just a new database instance. [This](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html) shows how to deploy your code to multiple environments. It will be suggested that you create a new project as the dev environment which will include a dev db and perform all development activities there.

Comment: @AkshayJain thanks this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Copying from the comments above. The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450439/separate-dev-and-prod-firebase-environment)

The solution is to have multiple projects as dev, staging and production environments. [Official post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html) by Google shows how to achieve this.