# Separate blue and green Google Cloud Platform projects?

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration

Similar to posts like this [Separate dev and prod Firebase environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450439/separate-dev-and-prod-firebase-environment)

I'm running into similar structuring issues. Unlike other posts like that that i've found, in my case, it's GCP as a whole rather than just Firebase. In addition, i'm looking at separation (or not) of blue and green deployments ALONG with the various environments.

The projects will be handling IoT data; mobile, field sensor/modules, web (in the future). Currently everything is unfortunately in one project.

So, i'm thinking of having 3 different projects for the staging, production, and test environments with each project having both blue and green deployments per, perhaps besides test but that's a different conversation.

Does GCP as a whole have documentation or recommendations about this? Or do you guys have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer because it depends a lot of your organization, your needs and your way of working.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy) you can find a google document about resources hierarchy.

However, I already see some GCP customers using only one project for dev/uat/prod because they share the same K8S cluster and separate the environment thanks to the namespace. By the way, the cluster maintenance cost is done only once for all the different steps of the project.

About the Blue/Green it depends on which component you want to apply this. If it's on the website, App Engine, or a Global Loadbalancer can do this. If it's about IoT Core or PubSub, I fear that you have to manage this by yourself or to create 2 different projects for this.