# Customer order tracking application

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to develop an android application for my personal business.

my application requirement:

1. Using this application customer can **track their 
   current order status.** eg: (order placed, under 
   process, under manufacturing, ready to deliver).
2. To store the **customer order history details.**
3. Application publishment is not required.
4. The application does not need any heavy interactive 
   GUI stuff, simple order tracking is enough for my 
   requirement.

I am an embedded developer, this technology is totally stranger for me.

Questions:

1. Who starts with android application development, 
   suitable IDE to develop an Android App?
2. It's a starting point for me so I 
   **is there a free server** I could use for this?
3. During the development period which server I can use 
   for the testing purpose?

Comment: The question is not suited for Stackoverflow in the way that it does not provide a specific problem that needs solving. I would suggest you either reframe your question very specifically. You can read this as well https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Who starts with android application development, suitable IDE to develop an Android App?

Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio

> It's a starting point for me so I is there a free server I could use for this?

You can try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) ([free to some extend](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)), although I would prefer some custom solution.

> During the development period which server I can use for the testing purpose?

Depends on what you choose in the above question. If Firebase check [Separate dev and prod Firebase environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450439/separate-dev-and-prod-firebase-environment), otherwise you will have a copy of the custom environment you setup.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable suggestions.