# Firebase preproduction stategy

Tags: firebase

I would like to know what is the best strategy for a preproduction process on Firebase?
Having a second firebase project linked to a specific branch and the main app linked to the master branch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exact solution available either from Firebase or externally. You'll need to create different projects, import/export database and storage etc.,

Check this answer - [Separate dev and prod Firebase environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450439/separate-dev-and-prod-firebase-environment).

Not sure if it helps, but there is an option to test locally before deploying it live. Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy).