# How to configure dev and prod instances of Firestore with `flutterfire configure`?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I currently have a "dev" instance of the Firestore configured for my iOS project in Flutter. Originally I followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios) and everything went smoothly.

Now, however, I also need to configure a separate "production" instance of Firestore for the production environment while also keeping the existing dev one.

Looking through the docs, there doesn't seem to be a way of achieving this through the `flutterfire` CLI alone.

My question is, what should be done exactly for 2 or more Firebase environments to be configured for a Flutter app on iOS? Do I need to "roll back" everything that was added by the CLI and re-configure everything manually?

Comment: For managing multiple environments it's best to create 2 separate projects for each of your environments as `dev` and `prod`, according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450439/separate-dev-and-prod-firebase-environment) and it's content links

Comment: Hi does that answer your issue ?

Comment: Hey, not exactly. Flutterfire generates all the necessary artifacts like plist files, etc. I was expecting that there'd be some kind of a solution to switching out those configs seamlessly between the envs. So far it looks like the best way to go about this is to use Flutter flavors

Comment: Yes as Flutter flavors allow you to use dependencies based on env, that should do the trick for you.