# In Flutter, is there a way to use a separate Firebase database for app testing, and then switch to using a real database when real users using app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is that I have already published an application, but for future upgrades, I need to test the app with a live database. Is there a way to use a separate Firebase database for testing the app? Alternatively, is there another solution to test the application while it is already deployed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450439/separate-dev-and-prod-firebase-environment?rq=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing flavors in your app. This will allow you to have separate `google_services.json` for each flavor in case of android and seperate `GoogleServices_info.plist`.

Follow this video to implement flavors in your application:
[Link to Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y7WaeU3P60)

Follow this medium article to integrate different firebase projects for each flavor:
[Link To Medium Article](https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b)

If you have used `flutterfire` cli,then you might need to configure separate
`firebase_app_id_file.json` for iOS,for that follow this medium article
[Link to Medium Article For Environment Setup](https://medium.com/capyba/setting-flutter-environments-the-capybas-way-cb7d085b3b74)

> You will need to add build scripts for google_services.json file and
> GoogleServices_info.plist file, In order to place them at the right location while creating a build. Those scripts are provided in these medium articles.